# Projectile at an angle. Finding the angle using conservation of energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, energy-conservation, projectile

Ball is thrown at an angle **α** and at the highest point it's potential and kinetic energy are the same. Find the angle. Use the law of energy conservation.

[image]

What the professor wanted

$mV^2/2 = 2* mVx^2/2$, $Vx=V*cosα$

$α=45°$

Here's what I did

$mVx^2/2 = mgh,  h=V^2*sinα^2/2g$

$tgα=1
,α=45°$

The thing that got me is where has the work gone. There were no conditions, neglecting wind, gravity, pressure, and we did last two.

I could calculate the trajectory but without any other dimensions I couldn't calculate **work**. So I just used the relation for **h** that we derived in class. Am I misinterpreting the energy-preservation. Should we subtract the **work** from kinetic energy at the beginning to get the energy at the highest point?

Could you tell me what forces are supposed to be ignored for the equation to work and are they ignored in the equation for **h**?

Comment: That second image is unreadable. Could you try using [MathJax](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to write those equations?

Comment: I changed it. Hope they are understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you're getting stuck on here is that you're still thinking about things in terms of forces and you seem to be trying to relate energy back to force via work. I know most classes start by introducing everything as force and acceleration, but you can solve this problem entirely by working with energy values. The idea here with conservation of energy is that in our isolated and enclosed system here (the projectile flying), we start with a certain amount of energy, and no matter what happens or where that energy goes, within that system we will always have the same amount of energy. In this problem, as the projectile gets higher and higher in the air, its potential energy increases. Since the total amount of energy in the system never changes, this means kinetic energy must be decreasing. We start with some amount of kinetic energy, but as the projectile gets higher in the air this kinetic energy gets converted to potential energy, and when we reach the highest point we have only half the kinetic energy we started with (but the same amount of total energy)

What's happening in the work you say your professor wanted, is that horizontal velocity is being assumed constant. In order for the horizontal velocity to be treated as constant, we must neglect air resistance.

By neglecting air resistance (and therefore treating horizontal velocity as constant), we can then reach the equality your professor gave, i.e. mVo^2/2 = 2 * mVx^2/2. This is because when the projectile has reached the highest point in it's flight, it's vertical velocity is 0, so the only kinetic energy the projectile has at that moment is from it's horizontal velocity. The kinetic energy and the potential energy at this point are stated in the problem to be equal, and by conservation of energy they must sum to the initial kinetic energy. In other words, the kinetic energy due to horizontal motion is equal to half of the initial kinetic energy.

At this point, we could use 'conventional wisdom' to say that if the horizontal contribution to the initial kinetic energy is half the total kinetic energy, then the vertical contribution to the initial kinetic energy must be the other half. If the energy due to vertical movement is equal to the energy do to horizontal movement, then the original horizontal and vertical velocities must be equal, so the launch angle is 45 degrees. However, your professor solves for this value algebraically (which is the more appropriate approach for academia).

Comment: Thanks for answering. How should I know that it's closed system? (Am I missing your point?)

Comment: It can kinda be a judgement call, but in most of these really simple systems like a car rolling down a hill, and there's NO FRICTION OR AIR RESISTANCE involved, you're dealing with a 'closed' system. And by a closed system, I'm mostly just referring to the fact that energy is conserved.